# postcss: BrowserSync is not working well with gulp, HTML and CSS are not being applied while changes are detected

Tags: javascript, css, workflow, gulp, browser-sync

```
var gulp            = require('gulp');
var browserSync     = require('browser-sync');
var reload          = browserSync.reload;
var postcss         = require('gulp-postcss');
var atImport        = require("postcss-import");
var nested          = require('postcss-nested');
var autoprefixer    = require('autoprefixer-core');
var cssnext         = require('cssnext');
var precss          = require('precss');
var nano            = require('gulp-cssnano');
var rename          = require('gulp-rename');
var cp              = require('child_process');
var jade            = require('gulp-jade');
var plumber         = require('gulp-plumber');
var uglify          = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat          = require('gulp-concat');


var paths = {
  'bower': './bower_components/',
  'assets': './assets/'
};

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['styles', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  var processors = [
    atImport,
    cssnext({}),
    precss({}),
    nested,
    autoprefixer
  ];

  return gulp.src('assets/css/main.css')
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/css'))
    .pipe(nano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src([
    paths.bower + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    paths.bower + '/Materialize/dist/js/materialize.js',
    paths.assets + '/js/main.js'
  ])
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'));

  return gulp.src([
    paths.bower + '/modernizr/modernizr.js'
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('_jadefiles/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('_includes'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('assets/js/**', ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_posts/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch('_jadefiles/*.jade', ['jade']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'scripts', 'jade', 'watch']);
```

This gulpfile.js is mostly inspired by [ShakyShane][1] of using Jade and Jekyll.

I am quite new to gulp.js tho, thinking to apply postcss to enhance my current workflow but changes are not happening in browser even they are detected in the terminal. Hope you guys can help.